# Intellij color scheme not working properly on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

Having tried multiple color schemes I am not able to get **Intellij IDEA v15** working properly on my **Ubuntu** box. I've upgraded from v14 but it had no results.

Am I missing something simple? No matter what I do (even modify colors in my custom color scheme) it looks like **only java keywords, comments and strings are properly colored**. Things like classes, fields, etc are always black.

Any pointers on how to get it working are much appreciated.

[image: this is java code sample in the editor]

Comment: Might be worth trying the [latest v16 build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+16+EAP) to see if its a version specific issue. Otherwise my guess would be that it isn't recognizing the file as a Java file somehow?

Answer (score 17):

In the Project pane, right click your Source directory and navigate to > Mark Directory As > Sources Root

I had this exact same issue, in addition IntelliJ was not identifying Java syntax errors, missing imports, and similar things.  Hope this resolves the issue for you.